# Создание приложения-галереи

Tags: android

Хочу создать приложение, в котором будет около `30`-`50` картинок (что-то типа портфолио), из требований.

Хочу что бы картинки подгружались из папки `res`, сама активити имела возможность *скролинга изображений*, изображения по тапу *разворачивались на весь экран*.

Много прочитал всего в интернете, кто-то советует `ImageView`, другие `WebView`...
Может кто подскажет или укажет на пример?

Comment: Вебвью вообще следует использовать только в самых крайних случаях. Вам хватит `RecyclerView` с `GridLayoutManager` и айтемами в виде `ImageView`.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую)

Comment: @post_zeew ну не то, чтоб в самых крайних, а скорее в тех, где надо html выводить

Comment: а можно, например, все фото залить в html и потом его из res вызывать во WebView?

Comment: WebView это вьюха для отображения страничек браузера (html +js), зачем оно вам, если ваши картинки лежат локально в папке res. ImageView создано специально для таких целей. и html в приложении это не ок (за исключением случаев когда без html никак)

Comment: Спасибо. буду делать как посоветовали